# Error while using the Data Import Wizard

Tags: custom-object, csv, data-import-wizard

I'm getting the following error while trying to import a UTF-8 csv file. I'm trying to import data into a custom table. Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

> Error while running java://ui.aura.components.setup.dataimporter.DataImporterController/ACTION$getStepComponent:{"name":"mapping","object":"Detailed_info_Newton__c","operation":"insert","mappings":"[]"} : a is null

sample content of the csv file:

```
NW.0001,NW.0001
NW.0002,NW.0002
```

Comment: Are there any required fields that you are not passing in your csv? You might want to test out your csv using the data loader first.

Comment: We have SalesForce Professional, so that won't work. I also tried the Excel connector which worked at some point but now only throws 5103 errors. I'm losing my hair and my temper..

Comment: Since everything goes through the API, if your user doesn't have API access then that's probably your issue.

Comment: I doubt that. The Data Loader is not listed because it is restricted to other versions, but the Data Import Wizard is listed which suggests it should work. Also the Excel Connector has worked - last friday was the last time I used it. Nothing changed on my part. It seems like the SalesForce API goes through periods or something.

Comment: The old import wizards should still be available. `Data Management > Import Custom Objects`. Try your import there maybe. I ran into this same error, too, but honestly can't remember why.

Comment: Did you use the "Drag CSV onto here" functionality? I had this problem when I used that. It stopped when I directly uploaded the file by clicking on the "CSV" section of the page.